# Can gcc inline an indirect function call through a constant array of function pointers?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, indirection, inline-functions

Let's say we have this code:

```
inline int func_2 (int a, int b) {
  return time() + a * b;
}

int main (void) {
  int x = (int (*[])(int, int)){func_1, func_2, func_3}[1](6, 7);
}
```

Can gcc be somehow tricked to really inline the indirect calls to `func_*`?

After compiling the code with `-O2` and `-O3`, I could still spot a `call func_2` instruction in the assembly output.

I know this hairy expression can be converted into a bulky `switch` statement with inlined calls for each case, but I prefer the former for its compactness.

Comment: Judging from your code, it looks like you're *really* desperate to get this working, aren't you? :)

Comment: Well, a bit of constant folding *should* allow inlining. But since it only works with constants anyway, why not call it directly?

Comment: @delnan: The real code uses a variable index, I just tried to minimize the code shown.

Comment: For me it's something obvious that you should use a constant index well known at compile time, or direct function call. Otherwise, linker will be unable to know what function implementation should be selected for expanding. Maybe macro concatenation (semantic sugar, though) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it does not hurt you to allocate some space in the data segment, you can try like this:

```
static int func_2 (int a, int b) {
    return time() + a * b;
}

static int (* const ftab[])(int,int) = {func_1, func_2, func_3};

int foo (void) {
    return ftab[1](6,7);
}
```

my gcc 4.4.5 correctly inlines the function with -O2.

The aggregate initializer inside the code of the function does not forward the constant as we expect, I don't know wheter it's a gcc bug or our misunderstanding of some C rule.

Comment: From comments, index supposed to be a _variable_ not a _constant_.

Comment: Sure, in that case, the answer is no, GCC won't inline all functions from the constant function table and automagically generated a switch.